# MATLAB Simple cell array Indexing. Please help :)

Tags: matlab, indexing

Forgive me for the highly novice question but I really hope I can get an answer quickly!

I have a 1x2928 cell array with 58x58 double matrix in each cell.
All I want to do is extract the value in (12,47) of each 58X58 matrix from the 249 cell array to the 280.

I bet the answer must be really easy but I have searched and search and I am teaching myself so any help would be so great right now!

Million thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this could help

```
cell{ii}(12,47)
```

with `ii = 249,...,280`.

Then you can use `for` loop or `cellfun` to run it over the index `ii`,

Answer (score 1):

A more complete answer:

```
cfrom = 249;
cto   = 280;
ri    = 12;
ci    = 47;
vals  = cellfun( @(x) x(ri,ci), cellArr(cfrom:cto) );
```

Comment: Your answer is the complete version of what I proposed. I didn't give it just to let the OP disclose it by himself.